# Getting class type from generics

Tags: android, generics, kotlin, functional-programming, factory

I have a generic type T inside my function and I need to get the Class type in order to send it to another function. I have read a couple of articles saying how this is hard to do in Java/Kotlin and have tried a couple of solutions but none of them worked.

This is my code:

```
class FishbrainViewModelProviders {

    companion object {

        private fun <T : ViewModel?> getClassType(): Class<T> {
            return (javaClass.genericSuperclass as ParameterizedType).actualTypeArguments[0] as Class<T>
        }

        fun <T : ViewModel?> getViewModel(fragment: Fragment, creator: () -> T): T {
            return ViewModelProviders.of(fragment, BaseViewModelFactory(creator)).get(getClassType<T>())
        }
    }
}
```

The problem here is that the `ViewModelProvider` returned by the `ViewModelProviders.of` has this `get` function that expects this `Class<T>`  type.

This is the error I am getting:

`java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType`

and it is happening on the `getClassType()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using [`reified`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters) type parameter? Note that it will require your method to become inline:

```
companion object {
    inline fun <reified T : ViewModel?> getViewModel(fragment: Fragment, creator: () -> T): T {
        return ViewModelProviders.of(fragment, BaseViewModelFactory(creator)).get(T::class.java)
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked! Perfect! Had not heard about this reified before. Super interesting.